# Three.js - Can we intersect with material ID of a model using raycaster?

Tags: three.js

I'have been trying to intersect only one material among 3 materials of the loaded model onclick using their ID's, however, the control continues to the entire model. Let me know if it is possible to intersec on basis of material ID's

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );

for ( var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++ ) {

    object.scene.traverse(function(child) {

        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

            if (child.material.name == "heap")  {

              child.material.color = new THREE.Color( 0x00ff00 );
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Do you mean, specify the material id when calling `raycaster.intersectObjects`?

Comment: Suppose, I should be able to click on character hand material to change its texture properties, can i do this by using material ID ?

Comment: If you're clicking on the hand, you can access the `.material` on the hand node and manipulate the properties - is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, how can i do that through raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the material of a raycast object by means of accessing the `material` property on the `object` of an intersection result. 
Something to keep in mind is that, when you do update the properties of a material object, you need to set `needsUpdate = true` so threejs knows that the material needs updating internally.

Consider the following code that achieves what you're after:

```
// If only interested in one intersection, you can use .intersectObject()
var intersection = raycaster.intersectObject( scene.children );

// If intersection found, update material in some way
if(intersection) {

  // Extract object and material from intersection
  var object = intersection.object;
  var material = object.material;

  /*
  Manipulate your material as you need to
  material.color = new THREE.Color( 1, 0, 0 );  
  */

  // Tell threejs that the material was changed and
  // needs to be updated internally
  material.needsUpdate = true; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach, can I narrow down this approach a little more ? Say that the intersection has to happen only for the hand and not to other parts of the model ?

Comment: Yes you're welcome, what is your criteria for identifying the hand ?

Comment: Based on material ID ?

Comment: So you know what the uuid or I'd of the hand material is?

Comment: Yes, i have mentioned the id in my example code above child.material.name == "heap"